# Makefile: Parametrizable recepie command in pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Assume the following makefile

```
objects = $(wildcard *.in)
outputs := $(objects:.in=.txt)

%.txt: %.in
    some-command $@ $<

compile: $(outputs)
```

This works as expected.

Now I want to add another target called (for example) `upgrade` that should do the same thing as `compile` but pass additional options to `some-command` (possibly depending on environment variables, but that is out of scope to this question).

The only 'solution' I've found so far has been recursively invoking the same makefile and passing the additional options via env variables. But that seems like a pretty ugly hack.

Is what I'm after possible in make (GNU is fine, this doesn't have to be portable) or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Target-specific variable value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
%.txt: %.in
    @echo some-command $(SOME_OPTIONS) $@ $<

compile: $(outputs)

upgrade: SOME_OPTIONS:=whatever
upgrade: compile
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.